# Advantage of State Machine over Delegation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, state-machine

I am currently working on an App with BLE. It has some complex functionalities. When my team implemented this in another platform, they end up in some problems and they use state machine to solve it. Now they suggested that to implement state machine in iOS also.

My question is, by doing this do we really have any advantage? Since iOS CoreBluetooth supports a very nice event handling via delegates(for events like disconnected, peripheral discovery etc),we can handle all the states using delegates. So what is the real difference in doing the same with delegates and state machine?

My app is to work in background for long time. Will the state machine implementation results in background execution problems? I read in docs that "try to minimise works in background". Is there any possibility that by running the state machine loop even in background results in termination of App?

Also will they affect anyway in app store submission. Please advice.

Comment: You can still use a state machine with delegation; the delegate methods simply provide the impulses that trigger the state machine to move to another state. A state machine doesn't require active looping. It is simply a way of describing the discrete states that your app can be in and the graph of permitted state transitions.

Comment: Thanks Paul! How we can implement it? Any working example. Going to try this:https://github.com/blakewatters/TransitionKit